# Cannot enable Azure Connect in Management Portal

Tags: azure, load-testing, azure-connect

I am new to Windows Azure platform and I am trying to set up Azure Load test. I have already set up Storage account, hosted service and Virtual Network. However, I cannot find Connect tab under Networks -> Virtual Network.  The prerequites i.e. Windows Azure SDK and Windows Azure Tools for VS 2010 have been installed. My local machine OS is 64 bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [previous Management Portal](http://windows.azure.com) to manage Connect VPNs. The new Management Portal cannot yet manage them. It's under "Virtual Network" tab in there. Also, this CTP must be enabled for your subscription(s) or it may not be present in the portal.

Comment: This was driving me crazy. All the MSDN articles refer to the old interface. To get to the old interface, click your email account in the top right corner and select "Previous portal".

Answer (score 0):

First of all Azure Connect is still in Preview and there is no significant improvements in this component for over a years so I would suggest not to use it.

If you really want to see Windows Azure Connect, it is only available in older portal so please go to older portal to see it.

Comment: Correct on all accounts. However, Connect is really the superior option if you're in a short-term transitionary status and don't want to go through the investments to setup true site-to-site VPN infrastructures. In this case, the Connect endpoint is much easier to setup! But as I said, I agree that this is by no means a good component of Azure to become dependent upon or invest in. We actually just removed our dependence on Connect ~1 week ago!

Comment: Is there a single tutorial out there on how to setup the "new" Network for use in Debugging? Every tutorial I've found references using Azure Connect so until I see otherwise what are the options?

Comment: What kind of debugging are your referring to? There could be others ways to troubleshot your problem rather then using network base debugging.